# Is openmp writing to the disk thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

My C++ program pseudo code looks like:

```
#omp pragma parallel
for (i=1...100000)
  write input files into a file called "$i.txt", $i is the value of i
  then do ./outside_program $i.txt and reads its inputs and do other stuff
```

Assume `./outside_program` is thread safe. Is using `openmp` to write to different files in `C++` thread safe?

Comment: Probably thread safe but possibly a nightmare in performance terms as the threads contend for access to the read/write head.

Comment: It seems likely that the I/O operations will serialize in the kernel or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing to different files I see no problem it is thread safe. 
The question is in fact not dependent of the multi-threading API you use. OpenMP, TBB, or other technology...